# Initialize jqgrid in a minimized state and only load data when maximized

Tags: jqgrid, lazy-loading, jqgrid-asp.net

For jqgrid, you can supply a caption.  If you do so, it creates a header with a button to minimize/expand the grid.

I have a page with several jqgrids. I'd like them all to start in the minimized state.  They should wait to load the data until a user clicks the maximize button.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the parameter [hiddengrid:true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) of the jqGrid. Be careful it works not with all datatypes (not for tree grids for example).

If you set the `hiddengrid:true` with

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {hiddengrid:true});
```

the setting will be default and will be used by all grids on the page which has no `hiddengrid` defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use jqgrid option scroll: true for infinite scroll pages.

```
.jqGrid({
            datatype : "local",
            data : JSONData,
            height : ($(window).height() - 250),
            width : ($(window).width() - 32),
            scroll : true, 
            rowNum:20, // the number of row's to be displayed the first time
...
..
});
```

check http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options
look scroll -- option.